# Locale aware number conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, localization

Is there a ***JQuery Plugin*** available that facilitates ***NUMBER LOCALIZATION*** ?
That is , the plugin should translate numerals into their local glyphs.

```
Arabic               |     ٤٣٢١      |   1234

Indic (Telugu/Hindi) |  ౧౨౩౪౫/१२३४५   |  12345
```

PS : My requirement is number CONVERSION , not formatting .

Comment: Please note that it is more of number conversion than formatting .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a simple function like this one for the translation *from* Arabic numerals:

```
function translateNumerals(input, target) {
    var systems = {
            devanagari: 2406, tamil: 3046, kannada:  3302, 
            telugu: 3174, marathi: 2406, malayalam: 3430, 
            oriya: 2918, gurmukhi: 2662, nagari: 2534, gujarati: 2790
        },
        zero = 48, // char code for Arabic zero
        nine = 57, // char code for Arabic nine
        offset = (systems[target.toLowerCase()] || zero) - zero,
        output = input.toString().split(""),
        i, l = output.length, cc;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cc = output[i].charCodeAt(0);
        if (cc >= zero && cc <= nine) {
            output[i] = String.fromCharCode(cc + offset);
        }
    }
    return output.join("");
}
```

And call it like this

```
translateNumerals(12345, "Telugu")      // "౧౨౩౪౫"
translateNumerals(12345, "Devanagari")  // "१२३४५"
translateNumerals("foo", "Devanagari")  // "foo"
```

The translation *to* Arabic numerals is equally simple. It requires just a little more plumbing.

The above function knows the charCode of the Zero in any target system and does some simple math to do a character-by-character conversion from Arabic numerals to that system.

A reverse function would need to check each character of the input. If it falls the charCode *range* of any source system (i.e. the charCode of the respective Zero + 9) it knows the required offset. Subtracting the offset will get you into the Arabic range. This is pretty trivial and I'll leave it to you.

---

**EDIT #1:** Since you mentioned jQuery, the above could be made into a plugin like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    textTranslateNumerals: (function () {
        var translateNumerals = function (input, target) {
            // the above function
        };
        return function (target) {
            // for each selected element...
            return this.each(function () {
                // ...look at each child node and
                $(this).contents().each(function () {
                    // ...translate text nodes, recurse into elements
                    if (this.nodeType === this.TEXT_NODE) {
                        $(this).text(translateNumerals($(this).text(), target));
                    } else if (this.nodeType === this.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        $(this).textTranslateNumerals(target);
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    })()
});
```

---

**EDIT #2:** FWIW, here is a function that can convert from *any* source system into *any* target system:

```
function translateNumerals(input, source, target) {
  var systems = {
    arabic:       48,
    devanagari: 2406, tamil: 3046, kannada:  3302, telugu: 3174, marathi:  2406,
    malayalam:  3430, oriya: 2918, gurmukhi: 2662, nagari: 2534, gujarati: 2790,
  },
  output = [], offset = 0, zero = 0, nine = 0, char = 0;

  source = source.toLowerCase();
  target = target.toLowerCase();

  if ( !(source in systems && target in systems) 
       || input == null 
       || typeof input == "undefined" || typeof input == "object" ) {
    return input;
  }

  input  = input.toString();
  offset = systems[target] - systems[source];
  zero   = systems[source];
  nine   = systems[source] + 9;

  for (var i=0, l=input.length; i<l; i++) {
    var char = input.charCodeAt(i);

    if (char >= zero && char <= nine) {
      output.push( String.fromCharCode(char + offset) );
    } else {
      output.push( input[i] );
    }
  }
  return output.join("");
}
```

Sample outputs

```
translateNumerals("0123456789", "arabic", "malayalam")  // "൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯"
translateNumerals("൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯", "malayalam", "arabic")  // "0123456789"
translateNumerals("൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯", "malayalam", "kannada") // "೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯"
translateNumerals("೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯", "kannada", "nagari") // "০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯"
translateNumerals("೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯", "kannada", "gujarati") // "૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯"
translateNumerals("USD 13.56", "arabic", "nagari") // "USD ১৩.৫৬"
```

Comment: @Tomalak : This is what I've been looking for . Thanks a ton ! +1 to it !

Comment: @CHOCY: Good to hear. :) Note that you can easily add more systems like Japanese katakana or hiragana numerals. *(PS: Please don't forget to accept the answer!)*

Comment: @Tomalak : This is good enough, just a clarification, are the numbers corresponding to each of these Languages are the base value of Zero in unicode ?
If yes, how would you represent Arabic Numerals, I am not sure ifthe one you've mentioned is Arabic.

Comment: @CHOCY Yes, the numbers are the Unicode codepoints of zero in the respective numeral system. You add support for more systems by adding the codepointof zero in that system. I thought that would be rather obvious. Why don't you simply try it and see what happens?

Comment: Isn't second argument for conversion function excessive? Since symbols in different systems are not intersected, determining the system could be done automtically.

Comment: @kirilloid Yes, you could do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is the jQuery Globalize plugin: https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Comment: nills, like I mentioned earlier, your plugin sure does help in number formatting . Not in conversion . Thanks anyways !

Comment: @CHOCY The way I see it parsing and subsequent formatting equals conversion.