# any jquery plugin for number conversion based on locale

Tags: jquery

I have use case where user with different locale use some page which is responsible for certain calculation.
However for calculation I have used javascript(parseFloat) which work fine for US locale when user other than this locale visit the page his locale gets applied & the calculation part shows strange result.

For example, a number  in the US as "1,250,500.75" would be written differently in different countries: "1.250.500,75" in Germany, "1 250 500,75" in France, and "1'250'500.75" in Switzerland, and "125,0500.75" in Japan.

Any any suggest a workaround for this / any jquery plugin that convert NUMBER based on locale & perform calculations.

Thanks in Advance !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Seems kind of similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091373/locale-aware-number-conversion-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a good solution for you: [number Formatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)