# Jquery number validation + India

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, number-formatting

This is a more region specific question. I am developing an application for India in asp.net mvc3.

I have a field which takes decimal values. The jQuery validation fails for this field if the numbers as entered in the Indian format.

Example:
Jquery works fine if I enter:

```
500000.12
```

or

```
500,000.12
```

But fails when this is written in the Indian format i.e.

```
5,00,000.12 // Fails with error - This is not a number.
```

In Indian format,

```
5,000 = 5,000
50,000 = 50,000
500,000 = 5,00,000
5,000,000 = 50,00,000
50,000,000 = 5,00,00,000
```

What should I do to ensure that jQuery validation does not fail for numeric fields?

---

I found the solution here: [MVC 3 jQuery Validation/globalizing of number/decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field)

Comment: Can you tell us more about the Indian format? Like in general for even bigger number, if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091373/locale-aware-number-conversion-in-javascript

Comment: nhahtdh - I have included some numbers in the original question. basically, the indian format puts a comma after every 2 zeros after 1 thousand. so 5,000 is same as 5,000 but 500,000 is 5,00,000 and any other big number would be .. 5,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,000. Hope that helps

Comment: Are you applying any regex rules..?

Comment: I have found a blog post .. will give this a try and let you know http://blog.brainnovative.com/2010/12/globalizing-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive.html

Comment: if you follow that link you will find a ready to use solution by the way ... don't ask for help if you don't want to read the responses .

Comment: The link you mentioned is to translate numerals ... my question was regarding validation.

Comment: I found the solution in  the jQuery Globalization plugin from Microsoft: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in jQuery Globalization plugin from Microsoft

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.globalize/globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.hi-IN.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        Globalize.culture('hi-IN');
    });
</script>
```

This is based on [MVC 3 jQuery Validation/globalizing of number/decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199835/mvc-3-jquery-validation-globalizing-of-number-decimal-field)