# greater than or smaller than check for gujarati numbers

Tags: java, javascript, unicode, numbers

I have a form, where user fills and Gujarati numeric numbers (in Gujarati), for eg. `૧૪` (which is 14). I want to make a check whether the entered Gujarati number is less than **50** (or `૫૦`) or not.

How can i make this check in java and in javascript?

Comment: Since Gujrati works on a decimal system, have you tried simply replacing the characters with the usual Arabic numerals and then performing the check?

Comment: @Manishearth I think he wants exactly the single-line doing this.

Comment: Found the solution on SOF only, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091373/locale-aware-number-conversion-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert it to an decimal and compare the result.

```
function gujaratiToDecimal (n) {
    return n.split ("").reduce (function (sum,chr,index,array) {
         var num = chr.charCodeAt (0) - 2790; //Subtract 2790 to get the decimal value for the current char
         num *= Math.pow (10, array.length - index - 1); //Multiply it with a power of ten, based on its position
         return sum + num //Sum it up
    },0)
}
gujaratiToDecimal ("૫૦"); //50
gujaratiToDecimal ("૧૪") < gujaratiToDecimal ("૫૦") //true
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/7Bnkn/)

I guess you could easily translate that to Java. -- *Just installed an IDE, heres a Java version*

```
 public int gujarati (String str) {
     int len = str.length ();
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
         sum += (str.charAt (i) - 2790 ) * Math.pow (10, len - i - 1);
     }
     return sum;
 }
```

Comment: There is a simpler method using Array.map(): 

return parseInt(num.split("").map( function(a){ return a.charCodeAt(0) - 2790; } ).join(""));

Comment: @Synthetx: I agree, that makes the code smaller. :)

Comment: @Synthetx That's totally true, but i thought, a more arithmetical approach would be more readable/translatable than a ducktyping one :)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 This is true :)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the uni-code values of characters entered. You can map those values with the values of 0-9 (e.g. ૧ maps to 1). Based on these, you can convert the number entered into Gujarati into one in English.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 said exactly what I suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work in java

```
public static int convertGujratiToEnglishNumber(String number) {
        int len = number.length();
        StringBuilder englishNumber = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = number.charAt(i);

            switch (c) {
                case '१' :
                    englishNumber.append(1);
                    break;
                case '२' :
                    englishNumber.append(2);
                    break;

                case '३' :
                    englishNumber.append(3);
                    break;
                           ....
                           ..... until 9 or (९)
                default :
                    break;
            }
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(englishNumber.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a java script function which populates a hidden text value same as "gujrati" text box. So if I am a user and I enter ૧૪ , a hidden textbox should get populated with 14 and then you can compare it with 50. My quick thoughts there can be better opinions.

Comment: Will not work always, the user may copy paste the number from somewhere (which i don't want to restrict).

Comment: you can call javascript or jquery function on focusout or tabout and populate hidden box.