# How to get the number from an input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have defined an input in HTML that represents a number. I need to parse the string in JavaScript to a number taking into consideration the different languages that will be entered by the user, for example: '1.34' in English will be written as '1,34' in French. `parseFloat('1,344')` will be return 1 in case we are in English standard.

Comment: You need to use a library that does the formatting. One such library is [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) but there are others, too.

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: [You are not the only who want to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645163/to-convert-string-to-number-according-to-locale-opposite-of-tolocalestring)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably find a library for it, but you can also pretty easily format the numbers into the wanted format yourself.

When you get a number from the input just convert it to string and then use the **indexOf()** function (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to see if there's a **comma** or a **dot** in the number. It returns the position index of that element in a string so you can then replace with the wanted one to format the number. Position will be **-1** if there is no dot/comma.

```
var num = 32.14;
var string = String(num);
var position = string.indexOf(".");
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only those two representations you consider, then another easy solution is to always do

```
var floatNum = num.replace(/,/g,".");
```

and then just treat it like any float number.

Unless you really need it for other number systems I'd avoid using a library. Libraries tend to be too big for most projects to utilize properly in my opinion.